# wp-config was suddenly updated

Tags: database, updates, wp-config

I have a WordPress site in which I have a normal wp-config.php with my credentials for the database, table prefixes etc. Now when I woke up this morning the file has suddenly changed to other values than it usually had which lead to an error on my site "Error establishing database connection". I quickly fixed the error by updating my wp-config with correct values again.

**But why did this happen?**

I noticed a Wordpress update to 6.0.3 around when the fault happened but I can't know if that is the cause. Can a Wordpress update change my wp-config file?

If so, should I disable Wordpress updates and only try them in my staging environment? Or is that bad practise due to security patches in Wordpress updates?

Comment: It's impossible to say with the information provided and you're unlikely to get an answer here. It could be nearly anything. The site could have been compromised and a malicious user made the change, or your host made the change for some reason. All I can recommend is that you contact your host to ask them help debug the issue.

Comment: @JacobPeattie The host was of no help. My questions is basically IF a Wordpress update can change my wp-config.php or not. But yeh you are right, it is not much information to go on.

Comment: Under normal circumstance, no, it shouldn’t.